# How to show UIImage in MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, mkmapview

I have an MKMapView in my View, and if I cant find a specific location I would like to show an UIImage in it. Is there any way I can do in swift 4?

Comment: So the requirement is to show imageView instead of a pin for the location ?

Comment: Well, I have a png image, and when I can't find any location that I set specifically I would like to show that png only instead of the map . Simply I wanna use MKMapView as UIImageView. Is there any way you know? @Nitish

Comment: In the parent view which has MKMapView, take an UIImageView and in the start, set it's visibility as hidden. Once you don't find the particular location, set MKMapView's visibility as hidden and UIImageView's visibility as vnotHidden. This is what I have got so far as per the requirement. However I won't suggest to display image instead of mapView. You could rather display an alert which says location not found

Comment: thanks a lot :) @Nitish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: mapView.frame)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YOUR IMAGE NAME")
    mapView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image as annotation in MKMapView with the help of creating a custom view with image view and set image at runtime and get image from view with the help of following code.

```
func imageWithView(view : UIView) -> UIImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)

    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let myimg : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return myimg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional add to Kosuke Ogawa's answer when i set frame as bound it solved my problem.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: mapView.bound)
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YOUR IMAGE NAME")
mapView.addSubview(imageView)
```